# How to access a C# library from C++ using Mono on embedded linux?

Tags: linux, mono, embedded

I am going to access a C# library from C++ in a embedded Linux system. The library is going to be made using Mono.

I have a large code base written in C++ running on a embedded Linux.

Because the C++ is unmanaged I can't just make calls to the library.

I was thinking about making a wrapper layer on top of the library and then using IPC calls.

I don't make the C# library myself, so maybe I need some kind of wrapper layer.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to the mono runtime (embed it), and then call it. See http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono